# Itunes Match ... how do I see the music that's been downlaoded to device?

Tags: iphone, itunes, music, itunes-match

I've looked a lot on the web for this and done a lot of trial and error on my end but I cannot for the life of me figure this out...

I have itunes match installed, it works great!  I can stream all of my itunes collection using wifi or celluar network.

It also has a neat option to download music to the device so that you can enjoy it when there's no data connection. However, how can I actually SEE what music is on my device and delete some music or manage it??  So confusing. If you scroll down a songs list, you can see indivdual songs that are downloaded to a device and delete them that way... howver, I just want to ideally be able to plug my iphone into my computer and see EXACTLY what music is on my device so I can delete some songs to add room.

I already have seen this link, but it doesn't exactly help me since I already everything listed for the information. http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202675

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see music thats specifically downloaded to your device, and only that music by going to:

Settings > Music

You will see an option for 'Show All Music' Turn this off. This will not delete any songs in iCloud nor change any other settings in your device or delete accounts related to iCloud or iTunes Match, this simply does what your requesting, only displaying actively downloaded music/videos. In fact, you can leave iTunes Match enabled and the results will conclude the same in your favor.

[image: pic1]

**EDIT** You can delete music thats downloaded to your phone in batches (currently by Artists only). However you can delete specific albums from that artist.

The following guide will take you to the respective settings:

Settings > General > Usage > Manage Storage (regular storage not iCloud storage) > Music

Here you will see a list of downloaded music only. **This is also where audiobooks are located!** Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the reply... yes, I know about that, but even then -  what if I just wanted to delete a lot of music at a time?  Ideally, I'd like to just be able to see all the music that's on my phone, and just manage and delete things from there, rather than having to go one by one track by track on the phone... seems kind of silly to even need itunes then if it just lets you see the music that's on there and not actually manage anything.

Comment: @Mixmastermichael Sorry, I was confused by the question, a more elaborate answer has been revised!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that helps a lot, however one thing - is that when I try to manage storage that way, it's not showing me ALL the songs that I have downloaded on my iphone as it does in itunes... for example, I've downloaded an album by an artist but it doesn't show up at all in the "manage storage" section but I know for a fact it's downloaded to the device, and it's also appearing in itunes... any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm not one to pretend like I know the answer when I don't @Mixmastermichael but that's the correct way to see all the data downloaded to your device. Anything outside of that may be circumstantial.

Comment: okay, well thanks again... at least I can see some of the music and manage it.  After doing some research on the web, it seems like there's a lot of people with the same issue.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6573939.  It's weird too, because there's albums I remember downloading from itunes match - but now they're not on the device in "music" but they show up in itunes and it shows that they're taking up a LOT of space. Might need to journey into hell aka my local itunes chaos store.

Comment: @Mixmastermichael again, it could be circumstantial, that doesn't mean that isn't the _correct_ storage location, it just means its not populating there. It seems to be a discrepancy with users who use iTunes Match, which kind of makes sense. It is fairly new after all , you could submit a [bug report](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/classicLogin.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3) for Apple to investigate.